About sequence of tenses in the past
If a main clause is in past simple and a subordinated clause is in past perfect but a subordinated clause has its own subordinated clause that happens simultaneously with the clause in past perfect, what tense will this subordinated clause of a subordinated clause stand in?
E.g can in the sentence

I remembered I had lost a gift that had been very precious for me.

the clause "I had lost a gift" be considered as a simultaneous one with the clause "that had been precious for me" or there in "that had been precious for me" has to be past simple to emphasize the simultaneous process?

The sentence looks clumsy with unnecessary past perfect clauses. It can be avoided by using adjectives.

Presumably the gift was still precious at the time of its loss, so there is no need to use the past perfect (which could imply that it no longer was). Use the simplest tenses which make your meaning clear.

It's not that you need to use past simple to emphasize that the gift was precious when it was lost; it's that you simply have to not use the past perfect since the past perfect suggests, but does not absolutely entail, that the gift had lost its preciousness before it itself had been lost.  There's no other reason to use the past perfect there.

You don't even need an explicit verb: "... had lost a gift precious to me".

I remembered [that] I had lost a gift that had been very precious for me.
You have a timeline:
PRESENT_______PAST____________________BEFORE (THAT) PAST_PERFECT________
           I remembered                [that]    had lost + had been

The had lost and had been precede remember.
Nothing here is simultaneous. There are two things that precede remembering but that does not mean they are simultaneous.
